# How can I find the file name in a directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, in the path `C:\Users\Username\filename.txt`, how would I print `filename.txt`?

Here is an example of a code:

```py
>>> x = input("Enter file path: ")
>>> Enter file path: C:\Users\Username\filename.txt
# Now print filename.txt because that is the name of the file in the variable x
```

Comment: Do you want the *name* of the file or its *contents* printed?

Comment: @ScottHunter name of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the path by `\` and get the last element (which is supposed to be the filename):

```
print(x.split('\\')[-1])  #  ==>  filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this intelligently is with the os module.

```py
import os 

Path = 'C:\Users\Username\filename.txt'
f_path, f_name = os.path.split(Path)

>f_name
'filename.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = input("Enter file path: ")
with open(x, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

method 1, you need to know the length of the filename:

```py
path = "C:\Users\Username\filename.txt"

file = path[-12:] # ===> filename.txt
```

method 2, using os.path.split:

```py
import os

file = os.path.split(path)[1]
```

method 3, using str.split. You need to make sure the path is seperated by '/':

```py
file = path.split('/')[-1]
```